# Ubuntu doesn't remember my keyboard layout options after reboot

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout

Recently Ubuntu 12.04 have started not to remember my keyboard options - as image http://img.ivanovs.info/XKnu0A.png

[image]

I always use Caps Lock to change my layout, and it used to work fine before. But now when I log in, changing it with Caps Lock doesn't work. I have to go to options, deselect "Caps Lock", select it again, and then it starts to work.

What may cause this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need change /etc/defaults/keyboard to:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru" <-- chagne appropriate to your language
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:caps"
```

or remove any entry in it since they are interfere with GUI tool from Unity/Gnome

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try it after a week when I come back from vacation.

Answer (score 0):

Strange thing. I used to switch on "Use Caps Lock LED to show the alternative layout", and all was fine. The problem began when I had switched that LED off to save my wireless keyboard battery power. Now I switched it back on and everything became fine again.

It seems that Ubuntu doesn't switch layout by Caps Lock after reboot if Caps Lock LED isn't used to show the alternative layout. Could someone reproduce the bug?